# AltBeacon - background scan configuration

Tags: beacon, altbeacon

Sorry for my English :)

I have no idea how configure scanner to work properly in background (using ScanJob). I noticed that if the ScanJob starts more than 15 minutes after the previous scan is finished, a passive scan occurs even though there are beacons nearby. The reason for this is that the max age of the region is set to 15 minutes and the region is not restored after ScanJob starts. For now, I do so that after the scanner returns the results, I check if the list from monitoring regions is not empty and if it is, I do

```
    if(beaconManager.monitoredRegions.isEmpty()) {
       beaconManager.startRangingBeacons (region)
       beaconManager.startMonitoring (region)
    }
```

to set the region again. If I do not do this, passive scan starts every ScanJob stops .
If I invoke

beaconManager.startRangingBeacons (region)
beaconManager.startMonitoring (region)
each time if application starts then ScanJob is canceled immediately.
I wonder if there is any pattern to the background scan setup?

Maybe just remove condition in MonitoringStatus class?

```
    if (millisSinceLastMonitor> MAX_STATUS_PRESERVATION_FILE_AGE_TO_RESTORE_SECS * 1000) {
                LogManager.d (TAG, "Not restoring monitoring state because it was recorded too many milliseconds ago:" + millisSinceLastMonitor);
            }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @davidgyoung I am trying to configure the scanner to run periodically in the background. I don't want to use the Intent scanning strategy because it call StartupBroadcastReceiver too often (Exhibiting bad behavior in Android Vitals)

Comment: @davidgyoung do you have a moment to analyze my observations -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/74010882/11383086

Comment: The library is not designed to support using the job scheduler for constant background scanning.  It just won't work, because Android does't allow running jobs that often.  The library stops the job as soon as it completes one scan cycle.  See my answer below for alternatives.  By default, you will get one scan every 15 minutes with the scan job strategy.

Comment: I don't need continuous scanning using scanJob scanning. I tried to describe another case. If the system starts ScanJob after 15 minutes, then the monitoring state is not restored. Which triggers a passive scan even though the beacons are nearby. Passive scan runs over and over after processing the scan results in ScanJob. Therefore, the application wakes up too often by StartupBroadcastReceiver

Comment: Here is the design of the library for this scenario:  (1) a passive scan is started if no beacons have been detected recently.  (2) If a beacon is detected by the passive scan, it triggers a new scan job to happen right away with `scheduleAfterBackgroundWakeup` .  (3) This will cancel the passive scan and start a regular scan inside the schedule job.  (4) One the job expires, beacons will have been detected recently, so no new passive scan will be started.  **Question:** Do you have reason to believe this is not working as designed?

Comment: @davidgyoung Exactly this scenario does not quite work as designed. I tried to describe it in the previous post. This scenario does not work when MonitoringState is not restored. It happens when the operating system first closes the application and ScanJob starts the application after e.g. 20 minutes

Comment: Okay, but in this scenario, the scan job (after 20 minutes) would either (a) find a beacon (making it in region and not starting a passive scan after the scan job completes) or (b) not find a beacon, in which case a passive scan would start, and any subsequent background wakeup would be justified.  Where is the problem?

Comment: @davidgyoung concept is correct but look at implementation. Each scanjob ends with method startPassiveScanIfNeeded(), and there is a condition which checks if(insideAnyRegion).  In scenario,
 where MonitoringStatus is not restored, insideaAnyRegion is false even if beacon is detected. Try to test startPassiveScanIfNeeded() in case where MonitoringStatus is not restored

Comment: But here is the key thing:  There are two different ways that `if(insideAnyRegion)` can be true:  (1) if MonitoringStatus was restored based on a previous in region status.  or **(2) if a beacon was detected as part of the ScanJob.** Why doesn't (2) eliminate the problem?

Comment: @davidgyoung If I look on startPassiveScanIfNeeded() method I only see insideAnyRegion initialialization by MonitoringStatus. Could you please show me a place in code where **(2)** case occures

Comment: The `mMonitoringStatus.updateNewlyInsideInRegionsContaining(beacon);` line of code [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/ScanHelper.java#L359) changes the region state to inside after a beacon detection in the scan job.  That line is inside the `ScanHelper` class whose  `mMonitoringStatus` is the same instance as the later call to `mScanState.getMonitoringStatus().insideAnyRegion()`.  So if any beacon matching a monitored region is detected by the ScanJob, that will cause `insideAnyRegion()` to be true.

Comment: Okey, but if you dive deeper in MonitoringStatus  the mRegionsStatesMap  is empty at the moment of call `mMonitoringStatus.updateNewlyInsideInRegionsContaining(beacon);` So calling this method does nothing, and finally `insideAnyRegion()` returns false

Comment: Why do you say so?  This would be true if no beacons are detected during the  ScanJob but I believe if one was detected this will not be empty.  This is how the code is designed to work.

Comment: Let's trace what happens there. I assume that MonitoringStatus is not restored, so `mRegionsStatesMap` is created [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/db4622cc4baad43d100333f85e40b4d2a4ae0637/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/MonitoringStatus.java#L205). Because `millisSinceLastMonitor` is greater than 15 minutes, so `mRegionsStatesMap` stays empty. If `mMonitoringStatus.updateNewlyInsideInRegionsContaining(beacon) ` is called in that state then `updateMonitoringStatusTime(long time)` is only called.

Comment: Maybe there have to be `restoreOrInitializeMonitoringStatus()` called again here  to fill out  `mRegionsStatesMap`?

Comment: Maybe like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286905/11383086)

Comment: Ok, but mRegionsStatesMap is also updated by `addLocalRegion` with a new region  when your code calls `startMonitoring(…)` at init time, and this gets used at the end of the scan cycle to make callbacks.    So if an app is killed by the OS and restarts >15 minutes later, the initialization process of the app (application.onCreate) will re-register the region.  Does your app not start monitoring in the application.onCreate call chain?

Comment: App not starts monitoring in the application.Oncreate, because I observe that ScanJob stops immediately after that. You can check logs [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZLGKLW85)

Comment: In the Android launch lifecycle `application.onCreate` is [always called before any service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate()) executes (including a JobService).  So  `application.onCreate` must be called before this line in the log: `ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@ac5cc06`.  Do you have code that calls `beaconManger.startMonitoring(...)` in the  `application.onCreate` call chain?  If you do then `mRegionsStatesMap` should not be empty.

Comment: Okey that's true, `beaconManger.startMonitoring (...)` must be called before `super.onCreate`  in class that extends  Application. But this can be hard to use for those just starting out with the library.I can`t see in the documentation that it is mentioned about this.

Comment: Fair enough.  But can you explain how you are calling startMonitoring otherwise?  The documentation shows an example here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html. You just cannot set up monitoring in an Activity or other view component an expect it to survive app relaunch.  If monitoring is started in a view, it is effectively foreground only and will not survive a relaunch.  The equivalent is true on iOS.

Comment: I don't actually need monitoring in my project. I want ranging to work properly when I using ScanJob.
But I think that calling `beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(...)` in `application.onCreate (...)` should be enough then `beaconManager.startMonitoring ()` can be
call anywhere only once.(Assuming that MonitoringStatus would be restored each time the library starts without TTL condition (15 min))

Answer (score 0):

The scan job strategy is the default way the Android Beacon Library operates.  It uses Android scheduled jobs to schedule scans and requires no configuration:

```
        val beaconManager =  BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)        
        val region = Region("all-beacons-region", null, null,       beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
```

In the foreground, scanning is constant and ranging callbacks come every ~1 sec.

In the background, scans are scheduled  only once every ~15 minutes due to Android 8+ job scheduling limitations, so ranging callbacks come at that frequency.  It is not designed for constant background scanning.

For constant background scanning you may configure the library to use a foreground service or the intent scan strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote an simple application.
App: Aplication looks like this:

```
class App: Application(), MonitorNotifier {

    val beaconManager by lazy { BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this) }
    val parser: BeaconParser =
        BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")

    override fun onCreate() {
        BeaconManager.setDebug(true)
        super.onCreate()

        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(parser)
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this)
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier { mutableCollection: MutableCollection<Beacon>, region: Region ->

        }
    }

    override fun didEnterRegion(region: Region?) {

    }

    override fun didExitRegion(region: Region?) {

    }

    override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(state: Int, region: Region?) {

    }


}
```

MainActivity looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val region = Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null)
    val beaconManager by lazy { BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
        beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
    }

}
```

in this app configuration, two cases are possible with the assumption that there are beacons nearby

**case 1**. ScanJob has been started up to 15 minutes after the last scan. After finishing work, you can see in the logs

```
ScanJob: Checking to see if we need to start a passive scan
ScanJob: We are inside a beacon region.  We will not scan between cycles.
```

and that is correct behavior

**case 2**. ScanJob has been started more than 15 minutes after the last scan. After finishing work, you will see in the logs:

```
ScanJob: Checking to see if we need to start a passive scan
```

it means, the passive scan has started. After a while, StartupBroadcastReceiver is triggered with the results of the passive scan. ScanJob starts to process the passive scan results. After finishing work, you will see in the logs:

```
ScanJob: Checking to see if we need to start a passive scan
```

it means, the passive scan has been started again and after a while the StartupBroadcastRetuver will be triggered again with the results of the passive scan. And so it will be over and over again for a while
when you start MainActivity again and call

```
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
        beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
```

In my opinion it is caused by the fact that monitoring state is not restored after 15 minutes from the last scan in the MonitoringStatus class (condition below)

```
else if (millisSinceLastMonitor > MAX_STATUS_PRESERVATION_FILE_AGE_TO_RESTORE_SECS * 1000) {
            LogManager.d(TAG, "Not restoring monitoring state because it was recorded too many milliseconds ago: "+millisSinceLastMonitor);
        }
```

and after the scan is complete, the method is called

```
   private void startPassiveScanIfNeeded() {
        if (mScanState != null) {
            LogManager.d(TAG, "Checking to see if we need to start a passive scan");
            boolean insideAnyRegion = mScanState.getMonitoringStatus().insideAnyRegion();
            if (insideAnyRegion) {
                // TODO: Set up a scan filter for not detecting a beacon pattern
                LogManager.i(TAG, "We are inside a beacon region.  We will not scan between cycles.");
            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    if (mScanHelper != null) {
                        mScanHelper.startAndroidOBackgroundScan(mScanState.getBeaconParsers());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    LogManager.d(TAG, "This is not Android O.  No scanning between cycles when using ScanJob");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and insideAnyRegion is false because the monitoring state has not been restored, so passive scanning is started even though the beacons are nearby.

To get this case up pretty quickly, I suggest you set MAX_STATUS_PRESERVATION_FILE_AGE_TO_RESTORE_SECS = 1, then when ScanJob start for the first time, you will see what I mean.

The operating system does not always start ScanJob after 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void updateMonitoringStatusTime(long time) {
    File file = mContext.getFileStreamPath(STATUS_PRESERVATION_FILE_NAME);
    file.setLastModified(time);
    restoreMonitoringStatusIfNeeded();
}

private void restoreMonitoringStatusIfNeeded() {
    if(mRegionsStatesMap.isEmpty()){
        restoreMonitoringStatus();
    }
}
```